# How do I Combine two CNN models (h5 format)?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, ensemble-modeling

I have two CNN models, both of them are trained on the same dataset.

How do I combine/ensemble both to make predictions on test data?

```
# Load Keras Models

model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model('/kaggle/input/models/model1.h5')
model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('/kaggle/input/models/basic_cnn.h5')
```

How to combine these 2 models to make `model3` ?

I have to use `predict_generator` function to predict from the ensembled model3.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a dense layer combining both outputs.

```
model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model('/kaggle/input/models/model1.h5')
model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('/kaggle/input/models/basic_cnn.h5')

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
combined = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([model1(inputs), model2(inputs)])
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_outputs)(combined)

model3 = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Set `input_shape` and `n_output` accordingly to your data and targets.

You should then freeze your pre-trained weights and train the final dense layer to correctly choose which weight to assign to outputs of your models.

```
model1.trainable = False
model2.trainable = False

model3.fit(your_data)
```